# NSDateFormatter produces wrong date

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I am converting a string to a NSDate with NSDateFormatter

```
1 NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
2 [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
3 [df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
4 NSDate *dueDate = [df dateFromString:@"1970-01-01"];
```

When I inspect the dueDate it is wrong by one year:

```
po dueDate
(NSDate *) $0 = 0x1cdc08d0 1971-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

Am I doing this wrong or might this be the same error as in the "Do not Disturb" function?

http://www.forbes.com/sites/adriankingsleyhughes/2013/01/03/apples-ios-6-do-not-disturb-bug-means-your-iphone-wont-disturbed-you-until-next-week/

Comment: running the same code gives me the proper date.

Comment: try with lowercase y in the format

Comment: That did the trick. Maybe you would want to write that as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: It's because the format string YYYY represent the "Year (of "Week of Year"), used in ISO year-week calendar. May differ from calendar year." So you can use yyyy